# In the sentence "if I see him, I will tell him", what part of speech is 'tell'?

Tags: parts-of-speech, infinitives

Intuitively, tell is a verb, but a verb that comes after a modal auxiliary is usually a bare infinitive, meaning it is a verbal and doesn't function as an 'actual' verb. Would it be correct to describe 'tell' as an adverb modifying *will*?

Comment: What if it was: “I will tell him if I see him.” ?

Comment: As a beginning learner of grammar, I do not see the difference. Would you care to enlighten me on how posing the sentence in such a way would make my sentence easier to analyse?

Comment: "I will tell him" is simple future, and tell is the verb. We have a separate site called [ell.se] for those learning English. This might he better asked there.

Comment: The reason I asked this question is because the reference material I'm using, the Farlex Grammar Book, mentions that the future tense is *will + the bare infinitive*. Is the bare infinitive and the base form of a verb interchangeable? I understand that an infinitive is a verbal that acts as a noun, adjective, or an adverb. Is my reference material incorrect?

Comment: Dump your reference material!. It is totally wrong. Verbs don't act as nouns, or any other parts of speech  -- they act as verbs. Infinitival clauses use the plain (or base) form of the verb. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not correct. "Tell" is a verb that serves as head of the VP "tell him", which in turns functions as a complement of "will".

"Tell" is in the form of bare infinitive, a form of verb that has no tense or aspect inflection and is not preceded by "to".